# Convert Segmented Time Periods in SQL Using Cross Apply & Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2008-r2

My core table data looks like this. It is keeping track of order statuses.

| ID | PartNum | EnteredOn | PickedTime | DeliveredTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 50A | 2024-03-28 08:59:13.727 | 2024-03-28 09:30:20.237 | 2024-03-28 09:56:42.570 |
| 125 | 60B | 2024-03-28 08:59:22.290 | 2024-03-28 09:31:32.543 | 2024-03-28 09:56:50.683 |
| 171 | 50A | 2024-03-28 14:31:28.480 | null | null |
| 211 | 70B | 2024-03-28 14:31:33.613 | null | null |

I need to write a query that converts it into this format:

| t_stamp | 50A_100 | 60B_125 | 50A_171 | 70B_211 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-03-28 08:59:13.727 | ENTERED | null | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 08:59:22.290 | null | ENTERED | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 09:30:20.237 | PICKED | null | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 09:31:32.543 | null | PICKED | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 09:56:42.570 | DELIVERED | null | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 09:56:50.683 | null | DELIVERED | null | null |
| 2024-03-28 14:31:28.480 | null | null | ENTERED | null |
| 2024-03-28 14:31:33.613 | null | null | null | ENTERED |

In words, I need to create a `t_stamp` column that includes each timestamp from the original table. I need a column for each ID named `[PartNum]_[ID]`. I need to return ENTERED, PICKED, or DELIVERED based on the column the original timestamp comes from. In cases where the t_stamp does not correspond to any information from a given column, I need to simply return null. I understand that there will be numerous columns if there are numerous ID's in the source data, and a ton of nulls.

Here is as far as I got. I can get the data I need for each ID manually by putting that into the `WHERE` clause, but I don't know how to use `PIVOT` to get a column for each ID + PartNum combination. Would `PIVOT` even be the proper tool here?

```
Select B.* 
 From  MyTable A
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES (EnteredOn,'ENTERED')
                     ,(PickedTime,'PICKED')
                     ,(DeliveredTime,'DELIVERED')
             ) B(t_stamp,[Status])
WHERE ID = 100
ORDER BY t_stamp ASC
```

That query returns these results. How can I incorporate each ID (from original results above) into its own column and insert nulls as described above?

| t_stamp | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-03-28 08:59:13.727 | ENTERED |
| 2024-03-28 09:30:20.237 | PICKED |
| 2024-03-28 09:56:42.570 | DELIVERED |

Edit:
I should have clarified; the part numbers should not be hard coded into the query anywhere as we have a very high quantity of these, and the source data might include just 1 part number or it might include 15+. Is this still possible?

Comment: I have change my answer to dynamic query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect your columns need to be dynamic.  If so, DYNAMIC SQL would be required, as you may know by now, SQL Server is declarative by design.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = (
Select string_agg(col,',') 
 From  (Select distinct id,Col = quotename(concat(PartNum,'_',ID)) 
         From YourTable
        )  A
)

Set @SQL = ' 
Select *
 From  (
         Select Item = concat(PartNum,''_'',ID)
               ,B.* 
          From  YourTable A
          CROSS APPLY (VALUES (EnteredOn,''ENTERED'')
                             ,(PickedTime,''PICKED'')
                             ,(DeliveredTime,''DELIVERED'')
                       ) B(t_stamp,[Status])
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(Status) for Item in ('+ @SQL +') ) pvt
 Where t_stamp is not null
'

Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: John, this ended up working exactly how I need. I really appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Data

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID            INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,PartNum       VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  ,EnteredOn     VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  ,PickedTime    VARCHAR(40)
  ,DeliveredTime VARCHAR(40)
);
INSERT INTO mytable(ID,PartNum,EnteredOn,PickedTime,DeliveredTime) VALUES 
(100,'50A','2024-03-28 08:59:13.727','2024-03-28 09:30:20.237','2024-03-28 09:56:42.570'),
(125,'60B','2024-03-28 08:59:22.290','2024-03-28 09:31:32.543','2024-03-28 09:56:50.683'),
(171,'50A','2024-03-28 14:31:28.480',NULL,NULL),
(211,'70B','2024-03-28 14:31:33.613',NULL,NULL);
```

Use unpivot and pivot together

```
select *
from 
(
 select CONCAT(PartNum,'_',ID) COL
  ,st,
  t_stamp
from (select ID,PartNum,
  EnteredOn as Entered,
  PickedTime as Picked,
  DeliveredTime as Delivered
  from mytable) m
unpivot
(
  t_stamp
  for st in ([Entered]
      ,[Picked]
      ,[Delivered]
      )
) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(st)
  for COL in ([50A_100], [60B_125], [50A_171],[70B_211])
) piv;
```

you can use dynamic query as follows

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max)
set @cols=(select string_agg(CONCAT('[',PartNum,'_',ID,']'),',') from mytable)
--print(@cols)

set @SQL='
  select *
from 
(
 select CONCAT(PartNum,''_'',ID) COL
  ,st,
  t_stamp
from (select ID,PartNum,
  EnteredOn as Entered,
  PickedTime as Picked,
  DeliveredTime as Delivered
  from mytable) m
unpivot
(
  t_stamp
  for st in ([Entered]
      ,[Picked]
      ,[Delivered]
      )
) unpiv
) src
pivot
(
  max(st)
  for COL in (' + @cols + ' )
) piv;

  '


--print @SQL
exec(@SQL)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nim6l3cd)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way to adapt this so I don't need to hard code the column names at the end? I would like the columns to dynamically come from the source data directly if that makes sense.

Comment: I tried a dynamic version but the column order is different https://dbfiddle.uk/NEQW2LuK

Comment: This may have fixed the column order https://dbfiddle.uk/rv15xW0G

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT  t_stamp
,   max(CASE WHEN partnum = '50A' AND id = 100 THEN Status END) AS [50A_100]
,   max(CASE WHEN partnum = '60B' AND id = 125 THEN Status END) AS [60B_125]
,   max(CASE WHEN partnum = '50A' AND id = 171 THEN Status END) AS [50A_171]
,   max(CASE WHEN partnum = '70B' AND id = 211 THEN Status END) AS [70B_211]
FROM
(
    VALUES  (100, N'50A', N'2024-03-28 08:59:13.727', N'2024-03-28 09:30:20.237', N'2024-03-28 09:56:42.570')
    ,   (125, N'60B', N'2024-03-28 08:59:22.290', N'2024-03-28 09:31:32.543', N'2024-03-28 09:56:50.683')
    ,   (171, N'50A', N'2024-03-28 14:31:28.480', NULL, NULL)
    ,   (211, N'70B', N'2024-03-28 14:31:33.613', NULL, NULL)
) t (ID,PartNum,EnteredOn,PickedTime,DeliveredTime)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (EnteredOn,'ENTERED')
                     ,(PickedTime,'PICKED')
                     ,(DeliveredTime,'DELIVERED')
             ) B(t_stamp,[Status])
WHERE   t_stamp IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t_stamp
```

This is just a garden variety conditional aggregation where the `MAX(CASE WHEN)` creates columns for each part you're interested in.